# KDE Frameworks deployment on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, kde-plasma

I am going to deploy a Qt Application on github and I want to link with some KF5 modules

I call the cmake command

```
find_package(KF5Crash)
```

and on linux the things are quite simple the user can

```
apt-get install libkf5crash-dev
```

I can mention on documentation the instruction on how to install kcrash or other kf5 modules, the problem is on windows, how can I instruct the windows developers/contributors to install any of the kf5 module?

Answer (score 2):

KDE developers use the Craft utility to deploy source and binaries of KF5 (and many other dependencies) to Windows.

See https://community.kde.org/Craft

Comment: Thank you Christoph I will check it out